# Haskell store user input in array

Tags: haskell, input

I'm learning Haskell and I would like to have user input x numbers into the console and store those numbers in array which can be passed on to my functions.

Unfortunately no matter what I try it doesn't work, here is my code:

```
-- Int Array
intArray :: Int -> IO [Int]
intArray 0 = []
intArray x = do
    str <- getLine
    nextInt <- intArray (x - 1)
    let int = read str :: Int
    return int:nextInt

-- Main Function
main = do
    array <- intArray 5
    putStrLn (show array)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need an `IO [Int]` in your base case:

```
intArray 0 = return []
```

and you need to change the `return` in your recursive case to use the correct precedence:

```
return (int:nextInt)
```

As an aside, `[Int]` is a singly-linked list of ints, not an array. You could also simplify your function using `replicateM` from Control.Monad:

```
import Control.Monad
intArray i = replicateM i (fmap read getLine)
```

Comment: aaa... I see, I forgot that return wraps things in IO stuff lol! And I have spent so much time trying to figure this out.

Comment: A bit off topic... is this a good way to store data into array or is there a more clever way?

Comment: @Reygoch - See update. If you want arrays in particular then Haskell has them in [`Data.Array`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.5.0.0/docs/Data-Array.html)

Comment: Also, `fmap read getLine` is otherwise known as `readLn`, except that the latter will give any parse errors immediately rather than when the value is used later.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen, `readLn` is okay, but you need to catch an exception to deal with parse errors. The (non-standard) `readMaybe` and `readEither` seem a bit more Haskell-flavored.